# Trying to Fetch data from API

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-volley

I'm currently working on an android application that displays weather information from an ASP.NET Restful Web API. I wrote a method that takes in a the city name and fetches the weather information and sends it to MainActivity where it will then be display to the screen, but for some reason, It would Toast the catch exception message. I tried looking at logcat for answers but nothing comes out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:

**Method used to fetch data from api**

```java
public interface WeatherByCityResponse {
        void onError(String message);
        void onResponse(WeatherInformation weatherInformation);
    }

    public void getWeatherByCity(String city, final WeatherByCityResponse weatherByCityResponse) {

        List<WeatherInformation> report = new ArrayList<>();

        String url = QUERY + city;
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    WeatherInformation weather = new WeatherInformation();

                    JSONObject weatherInfo = response.getJSONObject(0);
                    weather.setId(weatherInfo.getInt("id"));
                    weather.setCity(weatherInfo.getString("city"));
                    weather.setConditions(weatherInfo.getString("condition"));
                    weather.setMinTemp(weatherInfo.getInt("minTemperature"));
                    weather.setMaxTemp(weatherInfo.getInt("maxTemperature"));
                    weather.setWindDirect(weatherInfo.getString("windDirection"));
                    weather.setWindSpeed(weatherInfo.getInt("windSpeed"));
                    weather.setOutlook(weatherInfo.getString("outlook"));

                    weatherByCityResponse.onResponse(weather);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ooga booga", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Singleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe try to print some relevant information about the error you receive instead of a dummy string?

Comment: What is the actual Exception message?